# Eclipse e4 - Hiding Parts while Dialog is open

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

We are currently developing a Application in pure e4.

We have the Use Case that a ProgressMonitorDialog should be opened, while all open Parts are getting hidden.

Code:

```
IRunnableWithProgress runnable = monitor -> {
    Collection<MPart> allParts = partService.getParts();
    monitor.beginTask("Do Stuff", allParts.size());
    for (MPart part : allParts) {
      partService.hidePart(part);
      monitor.worked(1);
    }
    monitor.done();
  };

ProgressMonitorDialog dialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setOpenOnRun(true);
dialog.run(true, false, runnable);
```

The Problem is, that during the Execution (when trying to hide a part for the first time) an Exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not have an active window
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.getActiveWindowService(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:46)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.hidePart(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:145)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.hidePart(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:145)
at mine.lambda$3(Handler.java:100)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4213)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3820)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:165)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:369)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:483)
at mine.showProgressDialog(Helper.java:160)
at mine.execute(Handler.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:305)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:239)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:431)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:446)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.lambda$2(AbstractContributionItem.java:472)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:162)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

I also tried running the executing code with the UiSynchronize, but still getting the same exception.

Is there anything I can do to work with the PartService and with Parts while a Dialog is open?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the stack trace the `EPartService` you are using is the application part service `ApplicationPartServiceImpl`. This tries to delegate everything to the part service from the current part - but when a dialog is open there is no current part so you get this error.

Instead you need to explicity get the part service for your main window, with something like:

```
EModelService modelService = ... model service

MApplication application = .... the application

MWindow window = (MWindow)modelService.find("main window id", application);

EPartService partService = window.getContext().get(EPartService.class);
```